# Power of a statistic respect to significance level

Tags: statistical-significance, statistical-power

Let $Z_{1},\ldots, Z_{n}$ random variables i.i.d with symmetric continuous distribution  in $\theta$.

We consider hypothesis test
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
H_{0}: && \theta=\theta_{0} \\
H_{a}: && \theta>\theta_{0} \\
\end{array}$$

Let $T_{\theta}$ be a statistic, and let
$$\alpha=\mathsf{P}(T_{\theta_{0}}\geq c | H_{0} \mbox{ true})$$
is **significance level**, that is, reject the null hypothesis if $T_{\theta_{0}}(Z)\geq c$.

**My question:** What is the power of $T$?

**Remark:** We remember that

> **Definition.** The ***power*** of a hypothesis test is the probability of making the correct decision if the alternative hypothesis is true. That is, the power of a hypothesis test is the  probability of rejecting the null hypothesis $H_{0}$ when the alternative hypothesis $H_{a}$ is the hypothesis that is true.

I know that
$$\textrm{power}=1-\mathsf{P}(T_{\theta_{a}}\geq k|H_{a}\mbox{ is true})=\mathsf{P}(T_{\theta_{a}}\leq k|H_{a}\mbox{ is true})$$
where $k$ depend of $c$. **I do not understand as from $ c $ I can get $ k $ in general.**
For example, for statistic
$$T_{\theta}=\frac{\sqrt{n}(\overline{Z}-\theta)}{s}$$
It is easy to see the dependency of $ c $ (see [this link](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/book/export/html/245)). But it is not easy for the case of the **signed statistic**
$$B=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\psi(Z_{i}-\theta) \quad \mbox{ where } \quad \psi(x):=\left\{\begin{array}{ll} 1 & x>0\\ 0 & x\leq 0 \end{array} \right.$$
or **the Wilcoxon signed rank statistic**
$$W^{+}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\psi(Z_{i}-\theta)R^{+}_{i}$$
where $R^{+}=(R^{+}_{1},\ldots,R^{+}_{n})$ is the rank vector of $|Z_{1}|,\ldots,|Z_{n}|$.  ***I really have not been able to see that dependence in these cases.***

Answer (score 0):

In general, we have the relationship $\alpha \to c = k \to \beta_{\alpha}$, where $\alpha$ is the significance level of the test and $\beta_{\alpha}$ is the power of the test at the significance level $\alpha$. This allows us to consider the power as a function of the level of the test, which is useful when evaluating the actual usefulness of tests done at various significance levels.  So, the dependence of $k$ on $c$ is one of identity:  $k = c$.